How to create a new column from calculation of 2 number columns in Granafa
I am using Azure Managed Grafana. I am using 'Mixed Source' and I have 2 columns with 'number type'.
Say Column A and Column B.
I want to create a Column C with is equal to Column A/Column B * 100. Column A and B are integers. And I want Column C to be in decimals up to 3 decimals points.
How can I do that in Transformation?   I don't see any 'Math Transformation'
Thank you.
I don't see any 'Math Transformation' in Granafa. The only transformation I see is Binary operation

Transformation you are looking for is "Add field from calculation".
In Binary operation mode it allows to

Apply basic binary operations (for example, sum or multiply) on values in a single row from two selected fields.

So if you need to do A/B*100, you'd need to apply this transformation two times. Or drop whole *100, and use unit Percent (0.0-1.0) if that's what you are after here.
